# SelectedItems empty if multiple rows selected using different columns

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I have a `TableView` in `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE`. Using a `ListChangeListener` I'm able to catch the selection of multiple rows (by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

However my solution only works if the items are being selected in the same column **OR** in the area without columns. Gif for illustration with 4 examples:

1. **OK:** Selecting 3 items using <kbd>Shift</kbd> in State column
2. **OK:** Selecting 4 items using <kbd>Shift</kbd> in Idx column
3. **OK:** Selecting 4 items using <kbd>Shift</kbd> starting from State column to area without columns
4. **Error:** Trying to select 4 items using <kbd>Shift</kbd> starting from State column to Data Item column

[image: Selection of multiple items in different columns]

The problem seems to be that the `SelectedItems`-list is apparently empty in the last example. I'd really appreciate your help regarding this issue.

Here is my approach:

```
ObservableList<DataRowModel> dataRows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
dataRows.addAll(dataSetModel.getRows());
tableDataRow.setItems(dataRows);
tableDataRowStateColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().getState());

tableDataRow.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
tableDataRow.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()
.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends DataRowModel> c) -> {
    while (c.next()) {
        c.getRemoved().stream().forEach(remitem -> remitem.setSelected(false));
        c.getAddedSubList().stream().forEach(additem -> additem.setSelected(true));
        System.out.println(c.getList()); //Empty [] when selected using different columns
    }
});
```

Just for a better understanding of my code: `setSelected(...)` sets a `BooleanProperty` on my `DataRowModel` which is bound to the State-Column.

Without context the reason for using this selected-property seems to be quite silly. However, there are various other fragments of code with ChangeListeners bound to the selected-property.

**SSCCE ready to run:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private TableView<DataRowModel> tableDataRow = new TableView<DataRowModel>();
    private TableColumn<DataRowModel, String> tableDataRowNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Data Item");
    private TableColumn<DataRowModel, String> tableDataRowStateColumn = new TableColumn<>("State");

    private final ObservableList<DataRowModel> dataRows =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new DataRowModel("Concinna",  false),
            new DataRowModel("Concinna",  false),
            new DataRowModel("Concinna",  false),
            new DataRowModel("Concinna",  false),
            new DataRowModel("Concinna",  false)
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        tableDataRow.setItems(dataRows);
        tableDataRowNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().getName());
        tableDataRowStateColumn.setCellValueFactory(f -> f.getValue().getState());

        tableDataRow.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        tableDataRow.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()
          .addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends DataRowModel> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                c.getRemoved().stream().forEach(remitem -> remitem.setSelected(false));    
                c.getAddedSubList().stream().forEach(additem -> additem.setSelected(true));                
            }
        });

        tableDataRow.getColumns().addAll(tableDataRowNameColumn, tableDataRowStateColumn);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(tableDataRow);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class DataRowModel {
        private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", "");
        private BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "selected", true);
        private StringProperty state = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "state", "");

        public DataRowModel(String name, boolean selected) {
            this.name.setValue(name);
            this.selected.setValue(selected);

            this.selected.addListener((observable, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                getState(); // Refresh State value
            });
        }

        public StringProperty getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public BooleanProperty isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }
        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            if (this.selected.getValue() != selected)
                this.selected.setValue(selected);
        }

        public StringProperty getState() {
            String stateStr = "";
            if (selected.getValue())
                stateStr += "Selected";
            state.setValue(stateStr);
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while the image is nice - better would be a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem :-)

Comment: Added - removed some unnecessary things in the SSCCE to get the JavaFX code as condensed as possible :)

Comment: I was able to generate this by editing the Oracle's Person tableview example. This bug is filed as https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096787 , and fixed in 8u60.

Comment: Thanks! I've just installed the early access release and it works like a charm now. I've just looked up the official release date (GA), which should be in August 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to generate this by editing the Oracle's Person tableview example.

This is a bug, filed as https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096787, and fixed in version **8u60** which is expected to be released in August 2015.